# Image Export DayPilot Scheduler

Tags: java, c#, .net, daypilot

I am trying to export DayPilot Scheduler, using this code

```
DayPilotScheduler1.DataSource = dbGetEvents(DayPilotScheduler1.StartDate, DayPilotScheduler1.Days);//OPens only two Rows

DayPilotScheduler1.DataBind();

DayPilotScheduler1.CssOnly = false;

Response.Clear();

Response.ContentType = "image/png";

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=print.png");

DayPilotScheduler1.DataBind();

MemoryStream img = DayPilotScheduler1.Export(ImageFormat.Png);

img.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);

DayPilotScheduler1.CssOnly = true;

Response.End();
```

and the dates in the exported file dont cover all period from DayPilotScheduler1.StartDate to

DayPilotScheduler1.EndDate, but only the dates i see on the screen, like printscreen. What can

cause this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
DayPilotScheduler1.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
```